Firebase implementation in KMP
I'm following this post about how to add and configure Firebase when working with Kotlin Multiplatform. However, when opening Xcode and building, I'm getting this:

Calculating task graph as no cached configuration is available for
tasks: :shared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode Type-safe project
accessors is an incubating feature.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'remoti'.


Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.2.
Required by:
root project : > com.google.firebase.crashlytics:com.google.firebase.crashlytics.gradle.plugin:3.0.2
> Dependency requires at least JVM runtime version 17. This build uses a Java 11 JVM.


Try:


Run this build using a Java 17 or newer JVM.
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation
warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to
https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 2s Configuration cache entry stored.

I'm running Java 17 as I'm using sdkman for this and the current version is:
java -version

openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8, mixed mode)


Are you using Android Studio? Note that AS may sometimes use a different Java version than what you have installed on your machine. You could double check the JDK version used by your KMP project in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Gradle JDK as described in this other post

yeah, it's Android Studio and I'm using the right SDK: 17 which is set with sdkman. However this error happens when opening the iOS project with Xcode and I'm not sure why
